# How to do static file versioning like images available in asset folder in Angular4

Tags: angular

On updating a new version of my Angular4 site. The images are not re-downloaded on new version update. Browser continues using cached assets until we manually clear the cache. I am using ng-cli for deployment.

Comment: If nothing else you could probably just write a script to rename the files for you with Node and the FileSystem module.

Comment: That will require to update all the html and ts file where the images are referred. Need a simple and easy solution with example to do versioning of static files in Angular4

Answer (score 1):

You can use a version param in your image URL as follow

```
https://example.com/assets/images/foo.png?v=1.0.
```

Then you can up the version number whenever the image is updated to force the browser to refetch. (cache busting).

```
<!-- In your html -->
https://example.com/assets/images/foo.png?v={{assetVersion}}.
```